# How does the R package `terra` determine the number of dimensions of a raster projected without a template?

Tags: r, raster, gdal, projection, terra

I'd like to know how `terra` determines the number of rows and columns in a raster that is projected without a template raster.  For example:

```
library(terra)

from <- rast()
mollweide <- 'PROJCRS[\"Sphere_Mollweide\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Unknown datum based upon the Authalic Sphere\",\n        DATUM[\"Not specified (based on Authalic Sphere)\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Sphere\",6371000,0,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Sphere_Mollweide\",\n        METHOD[\"Mollweide\"],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Not known.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"ESRI\",53009]]'

to <- project(from, mollweide)

dim(from)
dim(to)
```

Inferring from the help for `project()`, it seems `terra` is using `gdalwarp` unless the user disables it, but the help [page](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) for `gdalwarp` does not elucidate.

Comment: That's because if you do not define raster, {terra} uses a build-in template, which generally has 1x1degree cells spread from -180/-90 to 180/90. You can check it just printing out `from`.

Answer (score 0):

The output raster geometry is chosen such that the extent and resolution closely match the input raster.

Comment: What is the actual algorithm? In the example above, how would I go from 180 x 360 (the dims of `from`) to 402 x 805 (the dims of `to`)?